# Implementing the sbox components using lookup tables

Tags: sagemath

Does it is possible to implement the components of a SBOX tables using lookup_tables. For example for a 4-bit SBOX it is possible to obtain the component 3 using SAGE in the following way

```
sage: from sage.crypto.sbox import SBox
sage: S = SBox([7,6,0,4,2,5,1,3])
sage: f3 = S.component_function(3)
sage: f3.algebraic_normal_form()
x0*x1 + x0*x2 + x0 + x2
```

But I need all components several times (like $2^{20}$), and boolean function substitution in SAGE is so slow to evaluate $2^20$ inputs. Then I think it is better to use lookup tables.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. That example is a 3×3 bit S-box (3 bits input, 3 bits output). The component bit numbers are 1, 2 & 4. The function `f3` doesn't give you the 3rd component, it gives you the XOR of bit 1 and bit 2. If you just want to look up S-box bits, you don't need those Sage functions, you can easily create lookup tables using standard Python bitwise operators (which also work in Sage, although you need to write `^^` for XOR). See the next comment for a brief demo.

Comment: [S-box demo](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjsGKwjAQhu95ijmtCcRg1VUo6MFX6LEUSWuiAc2EOEV9eyfqsru5zXx_vn98xgtc7dGZIT8Sobn2eIdwSZgJmh3ehYUNtGu90jO91HP9rSu96ETD24KlVSLlEEk2SnjMECBEkCVZqVoAP1-iZkB2Rhdp78c4UMAog3rx93dvKI902pPtz05OeDVRP2olRM8Sy5L04Imo3NT99mUbj04uPoVExqbk4kG2I3xBBSU3llzfvSuLjdl2-x-KlzHjrYxEbV1Pq67-cyQj9QRWJFkw&lang=sage)